# Headless Chrome rendering @media styles in large window size

Tags: css, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I am writing some python seleneium tests which involve hovering over elements and then checking the background-color style is as expected. I am using headless Chrome to run the tests as I am also taking screenshots for comparison tests. The window size I run the tests in is 1920x2700.

I have noticed that one of the hover tests fails, so I opened up the headless devtools to investigate and I noticed it is rendering the @media style (which is for mobile) rather than the standard style for desktop.

I have noticed that when I use the "inspect element" button while running headless Chrome in devtools that it renders is as if it were desktop (i.e. it no longer uses the @media style)!

Is this an intrinsic limitation of headless Chrome or is there a Chrome argument I can pass in that will force it to render desktop styles? (Unfortunately removing the @media style from the element is not possible as the styles are pulled in from an external library.)

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you testing on a browser that no one uses? Just run things in non-headless mode.

Comment: We are unable to take full-page screenshots in non-headless mode. The tests run fine in non-headless, so it is a possibility, but not a preference.